# Transient in RL circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance, linear-systems

Why the transient current will die off in series RL circuit with AC source?

Every time the ac voltage source reverses direction so does the current and the current has to pass through the same resistance and inductance every time. Voltage source, current, resistance and inductance all are same for every reversed direction and energy that electrons get in each reversed direction is also the same. Then why will the transient current die off with the passage of time ? I need intuition. Can anyone explain this to me please ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The OP might be confusing the *transient* and the *stable/forced* current. The *transient* processes occur when the conditions in the circuit are suddenly changed, e.g., when the ac source is turned on. By definition the transient processes last only finite time. The forced oscillations in the circuit driven by the ac source will have the same frequency  as the source, although their phase will be shifted in respect to the source oscillations.

When talking about *transient* processes, there is some ambiguity in what one defines as change of the conditions. Indeed, one could, e.g., consider as a change every time the direction of the current is reversed - but then everything is transient, and making the distinction between the transient and stable regimes does not make any sense. We thus usually consider as *stable regime* the ac oscillations that establish with time, after turning on of the ac sources.

**Remark**
One could also base the distinction on the predictability of the behavior: a periodic signal is perfectly predictable, whereas the momentw hen it is turned on is not. In fact, in comunication applications (radio/television/etc.) it is common to say that *only random signals carry information*, and only such signals result in transient behavio (usually characterized by the impulse response function of the circuit/receiver.)